# Pygame text will not render

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

My pygame based code will not render text. The text object is `gem_count`.

main.py

```
import engine
import color
import time
import sys
import random

try:
    if sys.argv[1] == "--debug":
        debug = True
        verbose = False
    elif sys.argv[1] == "--verbose":
        verbose = True
        debug = True
except:
    debug = False
    verbose = False

def player_step(obj, dx, dy, others=[]):
    if (obj.x + dx > 400 or obj.x + dx < 0) or (obj.y + -(dy) > 210 or obj.y + -(dy) < 0):
        return
    step_num = 0
    frame = 1
    for i in range(32):
        obj.move(dx/32, -(dy)/32)
        engine.background_image_fill("grass.png", 64, 64, 480, 288)
        for image in others:
            image.draw()
        obj.draw(frame)
        time.sleep(0.0025)
        step_num += 1
        if step_num == 12:
            step_num = 0
            if frame == 1:
                if verbose:
                    print("%s frame changed to: 2" % obj)
                frame = 2
            else:
                frame = 1
                if verbose:
                    print("%s frame changed to: 1" % obj)
    if debug:
        print("%s moved to x: " % (obj) + str(obj.x) + " " + "y: " + str(obj.y))

engine.init()

engine.window("8-Bit Miner", 480, 288)

engine.background(color.GREEN)

abandoned_mine = engine.Image("abandoned_mine.png", 80, 80)
mine = engine.Image("mine.png", 80, 80)
mine_abandoned = True

lantern = engine.Image("lantern.png", 0, 0, size=(480, 288))
#create player
player = engine.Animation(16, 16, size=64, frames=["player_idle.png", "player_walk_01.png", "player_walk_02.png"])

gems = 15

gem_count = engine.Text(str(gems), 80, 40)

print("Press:\nB to rebuild mine\nM to mine for gems\n")

running = True
while running:
    for event in engine.event_get():
        if event.type == engine.QUIT:
            running = False
            break
        for key in engine.get_pressed():
            if key == engine.RIGHT:
                player_step(player, 64, 0, [abandoned_mine if mine_abandoned else mine])
            elif key == engine.LEFT:
                player_step(player, -64, 0, [abandoned_mine if mine_abandoned else mine])
            elif key == engine.UP:
                player_step(player, 0, 64, [abandoned_mine if mine_abandoned else mine])
            elif key == engine.DOWN:
                player_step(player, 0, -64, [abandoned_mine if mine_abandoned else mine])
            elif key == engine.K_G:
                gem_count.draw()
            if player.x == 80 and player.y == 80:
                    if key == engine.K_B:
                        if gems >= 10:
                            mine_abandoned = False
                            print("Fixed abandoned mine!")
                            gems -= 10
                    if key == engine.K_M:
                        if not mine_abandoned:
                            print("Mining...")
                            engine.background(color.BLACK)
                            lantern.draw()
                            time.sleep(5)
                            increase = random.choice([0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4])    
                            if increase > 0:
                                print("Found %i gems!" % increase)
                            else:
                                print("Didn't find any gems.")
                            gems += increase
            else:
                pass

    if mine_abandoned:
        abandoned_mine.draw()
    else:
        mine.draw()

    gem_count.draw()

    player.draw(0)

    time.sleep(0.075)

    engine.background_image_fill("grass.png", 64, 64, 480, 288)

engine.pyquit()
```

and here is the code I am using to simplify some tasks:

engine.py

```
#Game engine
import pygame

QUIT = pygame.QUIT
clock = pygame.time.Clock

#Keys
LEFT = pygame.K_LEFT
RIGHT = pygame.K_RIGHT
UP = pygame.K_UP
DOWN = pygame.K_DOWN
ESC = pygame.K_ESCAPE
K_B = pygame.K_b
K_M = pygame.K_m
K_G = pygame.K_g

class ImageError(Exception):
    """Raised  when image loading or saving fails"""

class Error(Exception):
    """Raised for other errors"""

class Text:
    def __init__(self, text, x, y):
        self.font = pygame.font.Font(None, 30)
        self.text = text

        self.x = x
        self.y = -(y)
    def draw(self):
        global game_surface
        self.textsurf = self.font.render(self.text, True, (255, 255, 255))
        game_surface.blit(self.textsurf, (self.x, self.y))
        pygame.display.flip()

class Image:
    def __init__(self, image, x, y, rotation=0, size=(64, 64)):
        try:
            self.pygame_image = pygame.image.load(image).convert_alpha()
        except:
            raise ImageError("Cannot load image: %s" % image)

        self.x = x
        self.y = y

        self.angle = rotation

        self.size = size

    def draw(self):
        global game_surface
        if self.angle:
            self.rotated_pygame_image = pygame.transform.rotate(self.pygame_image, self.angle)
        else:
            self.rotated_pygame_image = self.pygame_image

        game_surface.blit(pygame.transform.scale(self.rotated_pygame_image, self.size), (self.x, self.y))
        pygame.display.flip()

    def move(self, dx, dy):
        self.x += dx
        self.y += -(dy)

class AnimFrame:
    def __init__(self, image):
        try:
            self.pygame_image = pygame.image.load(image).convert_alpha()
        except pygame.error:
            raise ImageError("Couldn't load the image")

    def draw(self, x, y, rotation=0, size=16):
        global game_surface
        if rotation:
            self.rotated_pygame_image = pygame.transform.rotate(self.pygame_image, rot)
        else:
            self.rotated_pygame_image = self.pygame_image
        game_surface.blit(pygame.transform.scale(self.rotated_pygame_image, size), (x, y))
        pygame.display.flip()

    def image(self):
        return self.pygame_image

class Animation:
    def __init__(self, x, y, size, frames, rotation=0):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.rotation = rotation
        self.size = (size, size)
        self.anim = []
        for frame in frames:
            self.anim.append(AnimFrame(frame))

    def draw(self, frame):
        self.anim[frame].draw(self.x, self.y, rotation=self.rotation, size=self.size)

    def move(self, dx, dy):
        self.x += dx
        self.y += dy

def init():
    pygame.init()

def window(title, width, height):
    global game_surface
    game_surface = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
    pygame.display.set_caption(title)

def event_get():
    return pygame.event.get()

def get_pressed():
    pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    keys = []
    if pressed[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        keys.append(LEFT)
    if pressed[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        keys.append(RIGHT)
    if pressed[pygame.K_UP]:
        keys.append(UP)
    if pressed[pygame.K_DOWN]:
        keys.append(DOWN)
    if pressed[pygame.K_b]:
        keys.append(K_B)
    if pressed[pygame.K_m]:
        keys.append(K_M)
    if pressed[pygame.K_g]:
        keys.append(K_G)
    return keys

def background(color):
    global game_surface
    game_surface.fill(color)
    pygame.display.flip()

def background_image_fill(image, img_w, img_h, win_w, win_h):
    global game_surface
    for w in range(0, win_w, img_w):
        for h in range(0, win_h, img_h):
            game_surface.blit(pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load(image), (img_w, img_h)), (w, h))

def mouse_pos():
    return pygame.mouse.get_pos()

def pyquit():
    pygame.display.quit()
    pygame.quit()
```

I can't see any problems in my code. So I have no idea why the `gem_count` won't render.

Comment: This is quite a lot of code. Try reducing it to a [mcve] first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In engine.py:29 you have

```
self.y = -(y)
```

This seems to put your text off the screen. Remove the `-` and you'll probably see your text. If you can't, commenting out the following might make it easier to see.

```
engine.background_image_fill("grass.png", 64, 64, 480, 288)
```